# IE7 on Win XP does not show download file dialog for PDF file

Tags: javascript, popup, internet-explorer-7, windows-xp

I'm testing the following JavaScript in our Umbraco site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(id, name, userId, siteId, siteName, breadcrumb, documentUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/myService.asmx/DoSomething",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{ 'id' : '" + id
                + "', 'name' : '" + name
                + "', 'userId' : '" + userId
                + "', 'siteId' : '" + siteId
                + "', 'siteName' : '" + sitename
                + "', 'breadcrumb' : '" + breadcrumb + "'}",
            success: function () {
                window.open(documentUrl);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've removed some stuff to leave the core function code. The actual web service call is working fine for both of the scenarios that I discuss below, it's opening the `documentUrl` that is causing an issue.

Now when I test the web page in a VM running WinXP and IE7 I encounter a problem. Instead of the script opening up a new window and showing me a PDF (or at least giving me the option to save it) all I see a quick flash of a new IE instance opening and then closing.

When I test the same page in IE9, on my Win7 laptop, and change via Web Dev Toolbar to render in IE7 mode, I can see the PDF file displayed (since I have Foxit Reader installed).

My question is this: Why in WinXP does the `window.open()` result in a quick show of a new IE window which then just closes?

I looked at Fiddler on both systems and found a difference. Under the VM, when requesting the PDF, the HTTP status is 206, which is partial content. Under IE9 the request is a HTTP 200, not a 206.

Can someone explain what might be going on here and how I can fix the WinXP IE7 instance?

I've been looking at the pop-up blocker settings in WinXP/IE7 and have told it to allow pop-ups for the domain I'm working with. I also disabled the blocker and I still get the same problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had not included `async : false` in the AJAX config. After doing that, IE was happy and now displays the download file dialog.